# Making associative array based on another associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, associative-array

I made an associative array as follows. To give a few details, the keys refer to specific files because I will be using this array in the context of a larger script (where the directory containing the files will be a getopts argument).

```
declare -A BAMREADS
echo "BAMREADS array is initialized"

BAMREADS[../data/file1.bam]=33285268
BAMREADS[../data/file2.bam]=28777698
BAMREADS[../data/file3.bam]=22388955

echo ${BAMREADS[@]}  # Output: 22388955 33285268 28777698
echo ${!BAMREADS[@]} # Output: ../data/file1.bam ../data/file2.bam ../data/file3.bam
```

So far, this array seems to behave as I expect. Now, I want to build another associative array based on this array. To be specific: my second array will have the same keys as my first one but I want to divide the values by a variable called $MIN.

I am not sure which of the following strategies is best and I can't seem to make either work.

**Strategy 1**: copy the array and modify the array?

```
MIN=33285268

declare -A BRAMFRACS
echo "BAMFRACS array is initialized"
BAMFRACS=("${BAMREADS[@]}")

echo ${BAMFRACS[@]}  # Output: 22388955 33285268 28777698
echo ${!BAMFRACS[@]} # Output: 0 1 2
```

This is not what I want for the keys. Even if it works, I would then need to perform the operation I mentioned on all the values.

**Stragegy 2**: build the second array when looping through the first.

```
MIN=33285268

declare -A BRAMFRACS
echo "BAMFRACS array is initialized"

for i in $(ls $BAMFILES/*bam)
do
    echo $i
    echo ${BAMREADS[$i]}
    BAMFRACS[$i] = ${BAMREADS[$i]} 
done

echo ${BAMFRACS[@]}
echo ${!BAMFRACS[@]}


# When I run this, I get the following error which I am unsure how to solve:

../data/file1.bam
33285268
script.bash: line 108: BAMFRACS[../data/file1.bam]: No such file or directory
../data/file2.bam
28777698
script.bash: line 108: BAMFRACS[../data/file2.bam]: No such file or directory
../data/file3.bam
22388955
```

**UPDATE**
Updated the strategy2 and it's output to be clearer.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both

```
declare -A BRAMFRACS
```

should be

```
declare -A BAMFRACS
```

that is, you have an additional 'R' in the name, the reason for one of the errors is that `BAMFRACS` was an indexed array (the default), not associative.

and in strategy 2:

```
BAMFRACS[$i] = ${BAMREADS[$i]}
```

should be

```
BAMFRACS[$i]=${BAMREADS[$i]
```

that is, no spaces around the `=` are allowed.  `BAMFRACS[$i]` is seen as a command, since commands are delimited by whitespace.

By the way,

```
for i in $(ls $BAMFILES/*bam)
```

could be written as:

```
for i in "$BAMFILES"/*bam
```

Try:

```
MIN=33285268

declare -A BAMFRACS

for key in "${!BAMREADS[@]}"
do
    val=${BAMREADS[$key]}
    BAMFRACS[$key]=$((val/MIN))
done

echo ${BAMFRACS[@]}  
echo ${!BAMFRACS[@]}
```

Gives:

```
1 0 0
../data/file1.bam ../data/file2.bam ../data/file3.bam
```